# How do I take video clips of my activity on the XBox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, recording

Is there a way to record clips of gameplay / dashboard activity on an XBox 360 for games that don't have a record feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Roxio Video Capture USB](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/creator/device/) and [Dazzle Video Capture](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Products/Consumer+Products/Dazzle/) devices allow you to redirect the RGB output from video game consoles to a computer.

[This product](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/techspecs/) from Blackmagic Design seems to record RGB, audio output, S-Video, and HDMI.

From there, you can record your PC screen, either with drivers from the companies of the products or with alternative screen-recording software.

*(Note: These solutions cost money to buy the products, but work for any devices that output via the formats listed.)*