# Starcraft 2 replays and screen capture software

Tags: starcraft-2, recording

I have a few questions:

1. How can I email a Starcraft 2 replay?
2. What can i use to record my computer screen without holding a video recorder in front of it?
3. What is the best deal for a capture card that has decent quality and where can i get it?
4. Can a capture card be used to record video on your computer screen much like it can for, say, an Xbox 360?

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to Gaming. I'd suggest dividing it into multiple questions by topic (not really four) -- I was going to edit it and fix formatting for you, but I'd be forced to remove your third question as it's not really appropriate for the site.

Comment: If you would need to remove it you can that is one that I don't really need. I can split it for you if you would like me to.

Comment: I suggested it so you could get better answers for your questions, you can ask about starcraft 2 in one, and about screen capture in another for example. I also think that has been asked and answered before, let me do a little search.

Comment: Here is the answer to your first question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/where-are-the-starcraft-2-replay-videos-stored-and-can-i-share-them, your second one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay, and your fourth: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-do-i-take-video-caps-of-my-xbox-360

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry that I made you do this. I'm a little new at this if you couldn't tell. =)

Comment: @Nick search is your friend

Comment: Please, it's no trouble at all, we are all here to help.

Comment: I finally went ahead and edited it a little (sorry @Kevin, we edit collided)

Comment: Heh, went and combined our edits.

Comment: Sorry that you guys had to do that I have never used a site like this.

Answer (score 7):

Your first question was asked and answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/where-are-the-starcraft-2-replay-videos-stored-and-can-i-share-them),
your second one [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay),
your third is not really appropriate, it's too localized and also subjective, there's not a real answer I can give you,
and your fourth is answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-do-i-take-video-caps-of-my-xbox-360).

Please read those, you can comment on them if you still have any questions about those topics.

Comment: Zing, nice compilation!